# Some fields in an aggregation query in MongoDB do not return to me

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called of `rewarded` that have a foreign key from the `hunters` and `rewards` collection, I would like to make a query that does not return me `hunter_id` and  `reward_id`, but return me `reward_description` (instead of `reward_id`) and `name_hunter` (instead of `hunter_id`).

- The MongoDB query

```
    db.rewarded.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "rewards",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "reward_id",
          as: "reward"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "hunters",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "hunter_id",
          as: "hunter"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          reward_description: { $arrayElemAt: ["$reward.reward_description", 0] },
          hunter_name: { $arrayElemAt: ["$hunter.hunter_name", 0] },
          done: 1,
        }
      }
    ])
```

- Returned result:

```
    [
      { _id: ObjectId('65ba2fa23dbbd4b08307e0b8'), done: true },
      { _id: ObjectId('65ba2fab3dbbd4b08307e0b9'), done: true },
      { _id: ObjectId('65ba2fb33dbbd4b08307e0ba'), done: true }
    ]
```

- That i expected:

```
    [
      { _id: ObjectId('65ba2fa23dbbd4b08307e0b8'), reward_description: SSS, name_hunter: SSS, done: true },
      { _id: ObjectId('65ba2fab3dbbd4b08307e0b9'), reward_description: SSS, name_hunter: SSS, done: true },
      { _id: ObjectId('65ba2fb33dbbd4b08307e0ba'), reward_description: SSS, name_hunter: SSS, done: true }
    ]
```

Comment: Your attempt seems [working fine](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rUV2kEpknY8). Can you post the raw sample documents? Guessing from the naming convention, you might have swapped the localField and foreignField